# Intellij IDEA Android layout editor ignores margins changes

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-constraintlayout

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2017.2.2 for Android app development. I have the following layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/image_x"
    android:id="@+id/text_x"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/edit_image_x" />

...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However when I open Design tab, I see that value of `layout_marginStart` is ignored and there is 0 in properties panel. When I try to set margin to other value, editor does not set `layout_marginStart` to new value, but creates `layout_marginLeft` what has no effect because there is still `layout_marginStart`.

This problem appeared after upgrade of Intellij IDEA from 2016.3 to 2017.2.2.
Is it a bug? How can I fix it? I don't want to remove all `layout_marginStart` from my code and replace it with `layout_marginLeft`. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Does https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64169967 look related?

Comment: Yes, it's similar problem.

Comment: I have noticed this same issue. There is an inconsistent use of the left and start margins.